# How to generate ATOM and RSS2 feeds with ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, rss, atom-feed

What steps are needed to adjust the default XML output of the ASP.NET Web API to generate ATOM and RSS2 feeds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to implement a custom MediaTypeFormatter.  You might want to check Filip's blog post on [RSS & Atom MediaTypeFormatter for ASP.NET WebAPI](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/04/rss-atom-mediatypeformatter-for-asp-net-webapi).