# Output Atom feed with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In my ASP.NET Web API project I have some standard Edit API calls where XML or JSON output or whatever the caller wants is OK for me. But some calls should return ATOM feeds.

Now I found out that I can achieve an ATOM or RSS output by a custom MediaTypeFormatter in this post: [How to generate ATOM and RSS2 feeds with ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750905/how-to-generate-atom-and-rss2-feeds-with-asp-net-web-api)

But it's not actually what I want as it's still up to the caller to request such an output by an HTTP Accept-header. I want to exclusively return ATOM here, no JSON, no  (serialized object as) XML.

Is it possible to do this with Web API? Or would it be better to use a standard web controller for those calls and only implement all other API calls as ApiControllers?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with web API too. Sample actions follow.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetFeed()
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, feedInstance, "application/atom+xml");
}


 public HttpResponseMessage GetFeed()
 {
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, feedInstance, feedFormatter, "application/atom+xml");
 }
```

You can use either one of these.

Comment: Thanks! Would upvote your post, but I'm not yet allowed to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a separate ASP Handler Page (.ashx) for this purpose if you want to force this form of output as the API should generically return what the user requests.

Comment: Thanks @aaroncatlin ... in this case, as the API should return a feed, nothing but a ATOM (or RSS) XML response would make sense so I wanted to restrict that. Those calls can be seen as API calls but also as content requests, kind of a grey area ... so while they would fit inside the API, it would be ok to have them outside of it in a regular web controller.

Going by an ASHX handler to abstract this call will sure work but I think it's not as clean as having a web controller for that.

So I'll go that route ... if it's not possible to easily restrict the output directly by WebAPI.